# Is there any better way to create {a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c} from {{a, 3}, {b, 5}, {c, 2}}?

Tags: list-manipulation

My attempt:

```
data = {{a, 3}, {b, 5}, {c, 2}};

output = Table[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ data // Flatten
```

> {a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c}

Comment: Also `Splice@*ConstantArray@@@data`

Comment: Benchmark: `Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ data` < *(Faster than)* `Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ data]` < `Splice@*ConstantArray @@@ data` < `Join @@ Table @@@ data` < `Flatten[Table @@@ data]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Join @@ Table @@@ data
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c}
> ```

or

```
Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ data
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c}
> ```

```
## & @@ PadRight[{}, #2, {#}] & @@@ data
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c}
> ```

```
## & @@ PadRight[{#}, #2, "Fixed"] & @@@ data
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c}
> ```

Comment: Also `Flatten[Table @@@ data]` and `Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ data]`